# Aggregation on Latest Records Of same status in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

I Have following data in ElasticSearch index `some_index`.

```
[ {
      "_index": "some_index",
        "_source": {
          "cart": {
            "cart_id": 1,
            "cart_status": "new",
            "grandTotal": 12,
            "event": "some_event",
            "timestamp": "2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "some_index",
      "_source": {
        "cart": {
          "cart_id": 1,
          "cart_status": "paid",
          "grandTotal": 12,
          "event": "some_event",
          "timestamp": "2022-12-02T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "some_index",
    "_source": {
      "cart": {
        "cart_id": 2,
        "cart_status": "new",
        "grandTotal": 23,
        "event": "some_event",
        "timestamp": "2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
  "_index": "some_index",
  "_source": {
    "cart": {
      "cart_id": 2,
      "cart_status": "paid",
      "grandTotal": 23,
      "event": "some_event",
      "timestamp": "2022-12-04T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
},
{
  "_index": "some_index",
"_source": {
  "cart": {
    "cart_id": 3,
    "cart_status": "new",
    "grandTotal": 17,
    "event": "some_event",
    "timestamp": "2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
},
{
  "_index": "some_index",
"_source": {
  "cart": {
    "cart_id": 3,
    "cart_status": "new",
    "grandTotal": 17,
    "event": "some_event",
    "timestamp": "2022-12-04T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
}
]
```

What I want to get is sum of the `grandTotals` by the latest `cart_status`es of each cart within a given time range. 
Having the example above, the result for `timestamp >= 2022-12-01 00:00:00 and timestamp<= 2022-12-03 00:00:00` should be something like 
`cart_status:new, sum grandTotal: 40` because within that time range latest status new have cart_id 3 and 2. 
and `cart_status:paid, sum grandTotal: 12` and this one because paid is the latest status of only cart_id=1. 
What I tried is to use `sub-aggregation on top_result, top_hits` but ElasticSearch complains that `"Aggregator [top_result] of type [top_hits] cannot accept sub-aggregations"`
Besides I tried with `collapse` as well to get the latest by status, but according to docs there is also no possibility to aggregate over the results of `collapse`. 
Can someone please help me solving this, it seems like a common calculation but not very trivial in ElasticSearch.
In SQL this is quite easy with window functions.

I want to avoid persisting intermediate data into another index. Because I need the dynamic query, as the users may want to get their calculations for any time range.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following way. meanwhile, for card_status, sum value will be 52 as it includes card_id 1 that has "new" as card status along with 2 and 3 for given timestamp.

**Mappings:**

```
PUT some_index
{
  "mappings" : {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp" : {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||strict_date_optional_time ||epoch_millis"
      },
      "cart_id" : {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "cart_status" : {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "grand_total" : {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "event":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Bulk Insert:**

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "some_index", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "cart_id" : "1" , "grand_total":12, "cart_status" : "new","timestamp":"2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "event" : "some_event"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "some_index", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "cart_id" : "1" , "grand_total":12, "cart_status" : "paid","timestamp":"2022-12-02T00:00:00.000Z", "event" : "some_event"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "some_index", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "cart_id" : "2" , "grand_total":23, "cart_status" : "new","timestamp":"2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "event" : "some_event"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "some_index", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "cart_id" : "2" , "grand_total":23, "cart_status" : "paid","timestamp":"2022-12-04T00:00:00.000Z", "event" : "some_event"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "some_index", "_id" : "5" } }
{ "cart_id" : "3" , "grand_total":17, "cart_status" : "new","timestamp":"2022-12-01T00:00:00.000Z", "event" : "some_event"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "some_index", "_id" : "6" } }
{ "cart_id" : "3" , "grand_total":17, "cart_status" : "new","timestamp":"2022-12-04T00:00:00.000Z", "event" : "some_event"}
```

**Query:**

```
GET some_index/_search
{
    "size":0, 
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2022-12-01 00:00:00",
                            "lte": "2022-12-03 00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
    "card_status": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cart_status"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "grandTotal": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "grand_total"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "took": 86,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 4,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "card_status": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "new",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "grandTotal": {
            "value": 52
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "paid",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "grandTotal": {
            "value": 12
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing that it should not be 52 for new, in this time range we should choose latest status of each cart, and aggregate by statuses. So within this range cart_id 1 has latest status of "paid", so we should ignore it's status "new" and within this time range not consider it.

Comment: I understand your scenario. but you can update your existing record with card_status as paid during the process instead of creating a new document. in this way, you can achieve your scenario easily.

Comment: we need all the history of statuses, in order to make analytics upon it and know exactly what statuses we had on a certain period of time.